# What are the chances of refusal?

Tags: canada, eta

I am a British Citizen with a dual nationality of the Syrian Arab Republic. I applied under the US ESTA visa waiver program for which I was refused.

I am now thinking of traveling to Canada knowing that my dual nationality won’t affect entry. However near the end of the application they ask if I have been refused a visa or permit to Canada or any other country.

I stated 'yes' and said I have been refused for entertainment using US ETSA and that my dual nationality may have been the reason of the refusal.

My application has been sent for review.

Will this be considered bad enough to be refused entry (I don’t have any criminal record and work full-time in the UK)?

What are the chances of being refused?

Comment: I'm afraid that this is highly opinion based, as we do not know the inner workings of the Canadian immigration authority, their decision making process or the type of day that the immigration officer reviewing your case has had...

Comment: But if you were an agent what would you consider on option based which may be the case in my suitation?

Comment: Im not an agent, so I cant give any opinion - I'm not even a trained immigration expert.  You have to sit and wait for the Canadian authorities to come to their decision, thats it I'm afraid - the only people that can answer your questions are the Canadian immigration authorities, and you have already asked them for their opinion on this!

Comment: My application was approved an hour after it was filed for reviewing.